# why does std::cin fail to throw an exception when I explicitly tell it to do so?

Tags: c++, exception, io, iostream, cin

I may be misunderstanding how `std::cin.exceptions` is supposed to work. Here is a simple example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::cin.exceptions(std::ios_base::failbit);
    int i=0;
    try{ std::cin >> i; }
    catch(std::ios_base::failure &b){ std::cout << "exception caught\n"; }
}
```

compiling with `g++ --std=c++11`, then running with an invalid input, such as a non-numeric character like 'f', does not throw any exception, e.g. I don't see "exception caught". This is confusing to me because I'm assuming that when attempting to read an int, `cin` will set the stream state to `failbit`, and the first line in my code says to throw an exception whenever this happens. In that case, why do I not see an exception?

here is the output when I type `g++ -v`

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

update: it seems to be a problem specific to the compiler described above, (or at least my particular copy of it). As noted by one of the comments, replacing by

```
std::cin.exceptions(std::ios_base::badbit);
```

doesn't fix the issue, but strangely,

```
std::cin.exceptions(std::ios_base::failbit | std::ios_base::badbit);
```

*does*.

Comment: Works fine here: https://ideone.com/FHkbdY

Comment: Also works fine here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/17ab6735f5826ca5

Comment: that's odd; I updated my question with my compiler info. Any particular reason why it wouldn't work on that compiler?

Comment: In my case, odd enough. Both `failbit` and `badbit` don't work, however, `failbit | badbit` works.... Mac OSX, clang++ 5.0

Comment: @liliscent i am getting the same. 4386427 that would catch all exceptions. the issue here isn't that I'm not catching an exception, it's that the exception isn't being thrown at all

Comment: It seems to be clang's problem, on my Ubuntu g++, `failbit` works.

Comment: The iostream exceptions are an in practice **unused feature**. One reason that it's unused is that encountering EOF sets failbit. Splat.

Comment: clang also works fine here: https://ideone.com/9nM1MM

Comment: @4386427 This is clang 4.0, old version. My clang++ version is the latest released.